# Not able to run jbossas7 on ubuntu on rackspace cloud server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jboss, java, rackspace

I am a novice on ubuntu (linux), i am trying to setup jbossas7 on rackspace cloud server,
I had installed jbossas7 and jdk6 on the server by uploading these files through ftp and then using command line through putty, it works well for about 24 hour , but after that it stops working, i think jbossas7 refuse to start, i tried many things including uninstalling and installing jdk. when i ran /home/cuelearn/jboss/jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final/bin/standalone.sh command  i am getting following error...

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
    at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.initAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:87)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:88)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(libgcj.so.12)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:75)
    at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:260)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem configuring DatatypeFactory
    at __redirected.__DatatypeFactory.<clinit>(__DatatypeFactory.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
    ...7 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException:                
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
    at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.12)
    at __redirected.__DatatypeFactory.<clinit>(__DatatypeFactory.java:62)
    ...8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
    at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.12)
    at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.12)
    ...9 more
```

Please guide me through this as i am very much under pressure because of this.

Comment: That libgcj.so looks a bit funny. Can you verify that you're using the 1.6 JVM you installed?

Comment: did you manage to set up mod_cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I got exact the same issue. I think you solved the problem already after two years. Just in case anyone else faces the same issue: simply configure the java path in standalone.conf. Then the server should start effortless. cheers